# How to pass intent to settings app for wifi

Tags: android, android-intent

i`m a very new in android development . currently I am facing a problem enabling wifi from my app . If my app is not connected to the internet I want to pass a intent to the settings app to enable the wifi and return to my app . how can I do that ? can anyone plz show me the trick .

## happy_learning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is quite easy . here is the solution 
if you have any button to enable internet in your app , you must need to call startActivityForResutlt method in this way .

```
internetButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    startActivityForResult(new Intent(
                            Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS), 0);

                }
            });
        }
```

and the onActivityResult() method would be like this

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 0) {
        WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        if (!wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()) {

            Toast.makeText(DuaCategoryActivity.this,
                    "something went wrong ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            //write your code for any kind of network calling to fetch data
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS));
```

For the complete list of Settings: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html